# Google OrgChart Missing tile

Tags: google-visualization, orgchart

Ok so I've added some data to the orgchart, however I found that if the same data would be on the same row with a different parent, only the first instance of that tile would be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I found that the issue can only really be resolved by assigning a distinct ID to the node, so in my case I combined the ID and ParentId to create the unique ID. this solves the issue.